# Use big spritesheet with 300 images Phaser.js

Tags: animation, phaser-framework, 2d-games, frames

Framework: **Phaser.js** version 3
**Symfony 5**
Langage: **Javascript**,
**HTML5**,
**CSS3**

Hello, I'm learning **Phaser.js** 3; I would like to create smooth animations (*25fps*) with lots of frames in my *spritesheet*. Is it possible to use large spritesheets to create animations without writing the name of each frame each time? If I have *230 frames*, I cannot write the name of each frame... Thank you in advance for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should be possible, you can generate the names with `generateFrameNames` or `generateFrameNumbers`, here is [the link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Animations.AnimationManager.html#generateFrameNames__anchor), and [here an example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/animation/generate-frame-names).

Or you can use a configuration file *(json)* to define the animations, like shown in [this example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/animation/create-from-sprite-config).
for this there are texture packer tools, for example this one  http://free-tex-packer.com/, that can help.

> **btw.:** If you want smooth animations, and havn't created the spritesheets already, may be (spine-)bones animations might be a easy and space saving option, here is two example from the official website http://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/spine/basic-spineboy and http://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/spine/batch-test
>
> *Here a short video highlights the benefits of bones for phaser games https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sq6mnix8eAg , it is very basic and not very technical*

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question @winner_joiner, I will be able to create my site/game with smooth animations. I've wanted to create a game with Phaser for a long time. Phaser.js that has a reputation for being easy to learn. Have a great day